# Objective C IOS - SingalR 2 don't connect in background fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, signalr, ios9

I have created an app with SignalR Ver 2.  SignalR works when the app is in the foreground, but when the app is backgrounded SignalR is not connecting! There is one thing I don't understand; when I test the app in the simulator using objective c it works and connects but it don't work when I send the app to my phone!

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"UserName"]) {
        //[self performBackgroundTask];
    }
    completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
- (void)performBackgroundTask
{
    NSString *buf = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"UserName"];
    connection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURL:@"http://yoursite.com/"];
    myHub = [connection createHubProxy:@"MobileNotification"];
    NSLog(@"%@",myHub);
    connection.started = ^{
        [myHub invoke:@"init" withArgs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: buf, nil]];
    };
    connection.reconnected =^{
        [myHub invoke:@"init" withArgs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: buf, nil]];
    };
    [myHub on:@"agentMessage" perform:self selector:@selector(notificationReceived::)];
    [connection setDelegate:self];
    [connection start];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            });

}

- (void)notificationReceived:(NSString*)RecipientId:(id)message
{
    NSDictionary *json = message;
    int RId = [[json objectForKey:@"RecipientId"] integerValue];
    [json objectForKey:@"Username"];
    NSString *body = [json objectForKey:@"Body"];
    NSString *time = [json objectForKey:@"CreationTime"];

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",body,time];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    static int i=1;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = i++;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [myHub invoke:@"UpdateStatus" withArgs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:RId],@"Delivered", nil]];

}
```

Please tell me what solution is better for background service and SignalR?

Best Regard 
Mani

Comment: are your enabled your background Fetch in project ---> target

Comment: yes i enable it ! it go to the line of background fetch but signalr is not connecting (invoke is not working)

Comment: I am also faced the same issue in signalr in last week so after that i found something in signalR some delegates not fired in background mode so on that I used notification center for catch the answer it is solved my answer

Comment: ok i read about that but there is no sample for signalR use on notification center . i try to understand it . if u can give me a sample plz